# Changing 2 dimensional list to a 1 dimensional

Tags: python, list, function, multidimensional-array

I want to create a function that takes a 2 dimensional list and outputs a 1 dimensional list with the same contents.
Here is what I have:

```
twoDlist= [[23, 34, 67],[44,5,3],[7,8,9]]
def twoone (list1):
    for x in range(len(list1)):
        for y in range(len(list1)):
            list2=[]
            list2.append(list1[x][y])
print(twoone(twoDlist))
```

Only problem it returns 'None'. What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here, the first is that you are not returning a value and the second is that you are resetting `list2` to an empty list inside of your nested loop, so at the end you would only have a single element in it.

Here is how you could fix your code:

```
def twoone(list1):
    list2 = []
    for x in range(len(list1)):
        for y in range(len(list1)):
            list2.append(list1[x][y])
    return list2

>>> twoone(twoDlist)
[23, 34, 67, 44, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, there are much better ways to do this, see the link in jtbandes' comment.

The best way is [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(twoDlist))
[23, 34, 67, 44, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your method returns `None` is that it does not have a `return` statement. Even with a `return` statement, however, the result is incorrect. As other answers point out, initializing `list2` outside the loops (and returning `list2`) solves the issue.

You could also use a nested list comprehension to accomplish the task more compactly.

```
def twoone(list1):
    return [val for lst in list1 for val in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that its happening is that you are reinitialise list2 as [] in every iteration. Try initialising the list2 part outside the for loop in twoone.

Comment: My bad, you need to also return the list at the end.